# Android- HOG descriptors distance

Tags: java, android, opencv, descriptor

I want to compare 2 HOG descriptors in an android application using OpenCV. I find difficulties in the computation of the euclidian distance beetween the two vectors that their type is MatOfFloat. Have you an example of code that can help me.

The fonction that computes the HOG descriptors is mHOGDescriptor.compute(imgMat, descriptors, winStride, padding, locations); the output of this funcition is descriptors that his type is MatOfFloat. Once i find the HOG descriptors for 2 images, I want to compute the euclidian distance between it and here exactly where I find problem.

I try this code but that does not work:

```
for(int i=0; i<imgMat.rows();i++)
{ 
    for(int j=0; j<imgMat.cols();j++)
    { 
        distance1=(int) (distance1+(mDescriptors1.get(i, j)-mDescriptors2.get(i, j)));
    }
}
```

Comment: The cv::HogDescriptor::compute function return a vector<float>. Is it what you want? If not, please add more information about what you are trying to do, and the code you are using.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. In fact, I am triying to develop in Java, and so the fonction that computes the HOG descriptors is  mHOGDescriptor.compute(imgMat, descriptors, winStride, padding, locations); the output if this funcition is descriptors that his type is MatOfFloat. Once I find the HOG descriptors for 2 images, I want to compute the euclidian distance between it  and here exactly where I find problem.

Comment: I try this code but that does not work:         for(int i=0; i<imgMat.rows();i++){    
            for(int j=0; j<imgMat.cols();j++){
           distance1=(int) (distance1+(mDescriptors1.get(i, j)-mDescriptors2.get(i, j);));}}

Comment: Please edit your question to add the additionnal information and code from your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems with your code:

1. It is not the correct formula for the euclidean distance
2. You convert to int at each iteration. It is not a good idea because the values of the descriptor are float and less than 1 (it is  composed of normalized histograms), so you round your distance to zero.

Try the following code :

```
distance=0;
for(int i=0; i<imgMat.rows();i++)
{ 
    for(int j=0; j<imgMat.cols();j++)
    {
        distance+=(mDescriptors1.get(i, j)[0]-mDescriptors2.get(i, j)[0])*(mDescriptors1.get(i, j)[0]-mDescriptors2.get(i, j)[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not work too. The type of mDescriptors1.get(i, j) is double[] so, the subtraction is not allowed.